# Windows firewall settings to receive UDP and pings

Tags: windows, firewalls, windows-10, udp

I use a windows 10 to receive UDP packets or pings from another computer which runs Win/Mac/Linux.

I default, I turn off the firewall to receive pings or packets.

I prefer not to turn off the firewall but having the previous functionality.

What settings should I use in the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

You said UDP or Ping so I am only going to show how to enable inbound ping.

First you need to open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

Next find the rule: File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In) (plus the others for IPv6)

Enable this rule.

You can see more here: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy or an alternate solution with custom rules from Microsoft: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749323(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To open any UDP ports, you can do the following:

- Go to Control Panel> System and Security and Windows Firewall.
- Advanced settings > right-click Inbound Rules and select New Rule.
- Add the port(s) you want to open and click Next.
- Select UDP protocol and the port(s) number(s) into the next window and click Next.
- Select Allow the connection and hit Next.
- Select the network type and click Next.
- Give a name for the rule and click Finish.

For ICMP, the quickest way to do it is opening an admin command prompt and typing:

**netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow**